# array.indexOf that matches with a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Trying to find a clean way to find the index of an array item in JS via a function (specifically for this case, regex-matching a string).

In Ruby, I've been using `array.index {|x| fn_to_match x}`, is there a JS equivalent of this? indexOf doesn't seem to be usable in this way, unless I'm doing something horribly wrong (very possible)

(FWIW, I'm running this in Node)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a helper function for that:

```
function indexOfMatch(array, fn) {
  var result = -1;
  array.some(function(e, i) {
    if (fn(e)) {
      result = i;
      return true;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but thought I'd should update to say there's now the `findIndex()` method which returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function (or -1 if no match found), so you can now use

```
let index = array.findIndex(fn_to_match);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 1):

Since the normal `.indexOf` doesn't accept functions, you can overload it like this:

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = (function(){
var old = Array.prototype.indexOf;

    return function(v){
    var i, l;

        if( typeof v != "function" ) {
        return old.apply( this, arguments );
        }

        for( i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i ) {

            if( v.call( this, this[i], i, this ) === true ) {
            return i;
            }
        }
    return -1;
    };

})();
```

Then:

```
var reTest = RegExp.prototype.test;

["ddd", "aaa", "asd"].indexOf( reTest.bind( /asd/ ) );

//2

["ddd", "aaa", "asd"].indexOf( reTest.bind( /ddd/ ) );

//0
```

Note that this is usable even if you don't wanna overload.. just do `Array.prototype.index = ...` or whatever name you want for it.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way:

```
var arr = ['bacon', 'blue', 'beach']

var i = 0
while (!/blue/.test(arr[i])) i++
var match = i < arr.length-1 ? i : null
console.log(i) // 1
```

`Array.forEach` could be used but you can't break the loop - it will go on regardless of a match. `some()` can be used but is likely slower.

You can also create a new method if you're comfortable doing that, or a standalone function:

```
Array.prototype.search = function(fn){
    var index = -1
    this.some(function(item, i){
        return fn.call(item, item) ? (index = i, true) : false
    })
    return index
}

var n = arr.search(function(){
    return this == 'blue'
}) // 1
```

Comment: `anArray.some` or `anArray.every` should be used if you want to break the loop (I would use `some` in this case).

Comment: Your `search` is buggy, it returns array.length-1 not -1 in case of failure, you shouldn't `index++`.

Comment: oops, I forgot to fix the second one.

Comment: Buggy again. It will fail if 0th element is the right one. The function in `some` will return `0` which will be interpreted as `false` thus going on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native solution. You may use `array.some` like this:

```
var index = -1;
if (searchedArray.some(function(v, i) {
  if (/*v is ok*/) { index = i; return true; }
})) {
  /* use index */
} else {
  /* not found */
}
```